# Access function result inside thread

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I'm working with Threads (again) and this is always pain in the... I have one function inside my thread class, and it's private. The function, returns one boolean result, to check if some POP3 server is valid or no. The checking is working, I tested it, and looks like working at least, but I'm having a problem to access the result when tryin it inside Thread.Execute procedure.. I'll explain more, let's go to the codes... Here is the declaration:

```
type
  MyThread = class(TThread)
  public
    constructor Create(HostLine: string);
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure MainControl(Sender: TObject);
  private
    Host: string;
    function CheckPOPHost: boolean; //this is the problematic function
  end;
```

So the function is something like this:

```
function MyThread.CheckPOPHost: boolean;
var
  MySocket: TClientSocket;
  SockStream: TWinSocketStream;
  Buffer: array[0..1023] of Char;
  ReceivedText: string;
begin
  Result:= false;
  FillChar(Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), #0);
  MySocket:= TClientSocket.Create(Nil);
  MySocket.Port:= 110;
  MySocket.ClientType:= ctBlocking;
  MySocket.Host:= Host;
  MySocket.Active:= true;
  if (MySocket.Socket.Connected = true) then
    begin
      SockStream := TWinSocketStream.Create(MySocket.Socket, 1000);
      SockStream.WaitForData(10000);
      while (SockStream.Read(Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer)) <> 0) do
        ReceivedText:= ReceivedText + Buffer;
      if Length(ReceivedText) > 0 then
        ReceivedText:= PAnsiChar(ReceivedText);
      if AnsiStartsStr('+', ReceivedText) then
        Result:= true;
    end;
  SockStream.Free;
  MySocket.Free;
end;
```

So, you don't need to read if don't want to. But I'm connecting into some remote host, and receiving it's text, if the text received begins with '+' symbol (default for POP3 servers), I return true... But when I try to do this inside Thread.Execute:

```
 if CheckPOPHost = true then
    begin
      Form1.Memo1.Lines.Append('Valid HOST:: '+Host);
```

Just don't work. I think is good to remember, that if inside the function, instead of doing:

```
  if AnsiStartsStr('+', ReceivedText) then
    Result:= true;
```

I do:

```
  if AnsiStartsStr('+', ReceivedText) then
    Form1.Memo1.Lines.Append('Valid HOST:: '+Host);
```

It works normally... What's happening?!

**Edit:: I'm getting error on 'if CheckPOPHost = true then' line. For some unknown reason it's giving Access Violation error.**

Comment: What does stepping through under the debugger tell you? You can do that. We cannot.

Comment: What's that PAnsiChar thing all about? Why don't you use AnsiString and AnsiChar?

Comment: Read the comment placed by the IDE automatically when you use `File->New->Other->Thread`. It specifically tells you **not** to access GUI controls from your thread without using `Synchronize`. Note the word ***not***, which is exactly what you're ignoring when you use `Form1.Memo1` from within your thread.

Comment: The debugger gives Access Violation on line if CheckPOPHost = true then... And the PAnsiChar is because it's working this way, I can try AnsiString and AnsiChar later, but this is not the problem...

Comment: I assumed that what didn't work was the function CheckPOPHost. Was that assumption incorrect? You really must explain how the code fails. "It doesn't work" is no good.

Comment: Well when running the .exe on compiler, it just shows the message: **Project Project1.exe raised exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access Violation at address C000013B'**. An just don't get inside the if CheckPOPHost = true...

Comment: Please edit the question so that it includes these details. Don't force future visitors to trawl through comments to work out what's going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling

```
SockStream.Free
```

even if you don't enter the block that creates SockStream. And that means your code can call Free on an un-initialized variable. That is the only reason that I can see for the access violation. You need to move the Free inside the if block.

As an aside, always use try/finally when creating objects:

```
SockStream := TWinSocketStream.Create (MySocket.Socket, 1000);
try
  ....
finally
  SockStream.Free;
end;
```

Had you written it like this, the compiler would not have let you put the Free in the wrong block.

You should do the same with MySocket.

And don't access you GUI from the thread, but I think others have made that point clearly enough!

Comment: This was the only answer that had really about the error.. Other guys talked about Synchronize, what wasn't the problem here...

Comment: To be fair to the others, once an obvious error is identified, it can be hard to see past it. However an AV at the address you reported is not readily explained by GUI thread issues.

Comment: @HwT - According to your accept, you don't even have a connection (code in the 'if' block does not run). But at the end of your question you state that, instead of 'Result:= true;' if you write ' Form1.Memo1.Lines...' *in the 'if' block* then there's no error. Either your question is misleading/wrong/nonsense, or you still have a problem to resolve.

Comment: @HwTrap: And also in fairness to others, at the time the posts were made about `Synchronize`, there was a **lot less** information available. You've added a whole lot more detail since. If you post a bad question, it's hard to give you good answers. David, +1. Nice to have info to work with, but you worked hard to get it too :-)

Comment: @Sertac Different code in body could change stack layout. And uninitialised var may be nil, say.

Answer (score 6):

You are calling non-thread-safe VCL methods from a thread.

```
Form1.Memo1.Lines.Append('Valid HOST:: '+Host);
```

Never do that.

Wrap the call in a `Synchronize( YourThread.SendString)`; method in the thread.

Example:

```
MyThread.SendString;
begin
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Append('Valid HOST:: '+Host);
end;
```

And somewhere in your thread execute:

```
if CheckPOPHost = true then
  begin
    Synchronize(SendString);
```

**Update 2:**

From your comments about freeing objects in `CheckPOPHost`: Enclose `try..finally` blocks around those objects and an additional `try..except` block inside your CheckPopHost.

**Update**

A discussion about the thread wizard in the comments arised.
This is what you get if you create a thread unit following the wizard interface:

```
unit Unit21;

interface

uses
  System.Classes;

type
  TMYTHREADTEST = class(TThread)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

implementation

{
  Important: Methods and properties of objects in visual components can only be
  used in a method called using Synchronize, for example,

      Synchronize(UpdateCaption);

  and UpdateCaption could look like,

    procedure TMYTHREADTEST.UpdateCaption;
    begin
      Form1.Caption := 'Updated in a thread';
    end;

    or

    Synchronize( 
      procedure
      begin
        Form1.Caption := 'Updated in thread via an anonymous method' 
      end
      )
    );

  where an anonymous method is passed.

  Similarly, the developer can call the Queue method with similar parameters as 
  above, instead passing another TThread class as the first parameter, putting
  the calling thread in a queue with the other thread.

}

{ TMYTHREADTEST }

procedure TMYTHREADTEST.Execute;
begin
  { Place thread code here }
end;

end.
```

Comment: +1. It's amazing to me that `TThread` is (AFAIK) the only new unit the IDE creates that has a big comment block at the start of the implementation section telling you about using `Synchronize`, but nobody can ever seem to see it. :-) I mean, it takes up the whole editor window when the thread unit is first created, and it's centered in the editor window.

Comment: Yes i know, but i'm just testing, and don't think this is the problem...Once the debugger is getting error in ' if CheckPOPHost = true' line...

Comment: @HwTrap: The debugger wouldn't have a problem on that line. The compiler might, but the debugger won't. What makes you think it's the debugger?

Comment: @HwTrap well, use OutputDebugString or some such instead so that we can rule this out.

Comment: Well when running the .exe on compiler, it just shows the message: **Project Project1.exe raised exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access Violation at address C000013B'**. And just don't get inside the if CheckPOPHost = true...

Comment: @KenWhite: That's assuming, of course, that you're creating your new thread from the special option for it in the IDE, which requires knowing that it's there and where to find it. It's not obvious at all.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: The D2007 docs on TThread specifically mention not accessing GUI controls (actually, so does D7 and XE, the three versions I have available to check). If the poster knows enough to manually code a TThread without allowing the IDE to do it for them, they should already know this (it's only been posted in every discussion of updating the GUI from a Delphi thread for a decade now, and is included in the TThread demo that ships with the IDE as well as that code comment I mentioned).

Comment: @Ken: True enough. I was just pointing out that the IDE thread wizard is non-obvious. Heck, I didn't even know it existed until I read your comment here!

Comment: @Mason: Ah, got it. Thought you were referring to the need to use `Synchronize`. :-) I didn't realize people might not know about the wizard; it generates the basic shell of a new thread (including allowing it to be named in newer IDE versions). It's been there since `TThread` was introduced in D2.

Comment: @Ken I'm with Mason. I never knew there was a wizard. Does it include helpful stuff like { private declarations } or is it more highbrow? ;-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, for what the wizard creates, see updated answer.

Comment: @David: It generates a basic class declaration (based on `TThread`), with `private` and `protected` sections and a declaration and implementation of `Execute`.

Comment: Looks like I figured out the error, but haven't one explanation for this... I removed **SockStream.Free; and MySocket.Free;** from my function, and it worked...

Comment: @HwTrap, you should enclose `try..finally` blocks around those objects and an additional `try..except` block inside your `CheckPopHost`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, you are correct. Just a safety precaution if something else is happening. The creation of `TWinSocketStream` can throw exceptions.

Comment: And those exceptions should not be swallowed, but instead propogated to a high level handler

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, no mention of swallowing, the exception should be handled either in the `CheckPopHost` or in the thread execute method. Or do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: Such an exception is probably terminal. So I'd say let it be caught by the thread wrapper that calls Execute.